# Form application encoded value is not working in spring rest

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have the below post request and of which below is the controller code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(/flow", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)

@Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping("{abcCode}/token")
    public TokenResponse createToken(@PathVariable("abcCode") String abcCode,
            @RequestParam("grant_type") String grantType,
            @RequestParam String code,
            @RequestParam("redirect_uri") String redirectUri,
            @RequestParam String clientId) {
        LOG.info(
                "Received call for createIdToken for abcCode: {} , clientId: {} , grantType:  {} ,code: {} , redirectUri: {}",
                abcCode, clientId, grantType, code, redirectUri);


                }
```

Now the problem is that when I test the same above controller through postman by choosing the body type as application form-encoded then it is working fine but when I choose the body type as none in postman and just pass the above request parameters as query one then also it works which ideally it should not please advise how can I overcome from the same

http://localhost:19080/testService/flow/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=3272&redirect_uri=http://www.abchui.com&clientId=ATS

it should not work for the above URL

Comment: That is what you configured to only work, request parameters. That is what is in your toplevel `@RequestMapping`. Your  `@PostMapping` will honor that config. So remove the `consumes` from your toplevel `@RequestMapping` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From spring sources:

```
public static final String APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

[According to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), when using url-form-encoded data pass as query params.
Try to change form mime type.